# Populating a highchart graph from a linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, highcharts

I am trying to populate a chart with data from my database. I'm using Entity framework and fairly new to asp.net.

What I'm trying to do is populate the chart from my linq query.

```
 var totals = from s in db.ClassInstanceDetails.Include("ClassInstance")
                 where s.ClassInstance.ClassID == 2
                    group s by s.ClassInstance.Date into grouped
                    select new
                    {
                        CIDate = grouped.Key,
                        TotalStudentsInClass = grouped.Count(s => s.Attendance)
                    };
```

The linq query works fine, it counts all the students in a classinstance, groups them and counts them. My problem is how do extract the data and put it into the chart. When I debug I can see that the totals variable is

```
{System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<<>f__AnonymousType0<System.DateTime,int>>}
```

and I can see the results view held by totals as :

```
{CIDate = {04/09/2012}, TotalStudentsInClass = 5}
{CIDate = {05/09/2012}, TotalStudentsInClass = 7}
{CIDate = {06/09/2012}, TotalStudentsInClass = 14}
```

Which is great as the query works, it finds how many pupils attended a particular class instance. I'm trying to put this data into a line graph using highcharts. I've tried to separate the linq results into 2 arrays one array containing the dates and another array containing the TotalStudentsInClass value but having no luck as the types are different??? Is this even the right way to do this?

The example I found online pulls from an array I think

```
.SetSeries(new[]
                       {
                           new Series { Name = "Tokyo", Data = new Data(ChartsData.TokioData) },
                           new Series { Name = "New York", Data = new Data(ChartsData.NewYorkData) },
                           new Series { Name = "Berlin", Data = new Data(ChartsData.BerlinData) },
                           new Series { Name = "London", Data = new Data(ChartsData.LondonData) }
                       }
```

with the data coming from an object,

```
public static object[] TokioData = new object[] { 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6 };
```

I've tried to run my linq query into an object but that throws me more errors than I know what to do with!!

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Comment: Are you using dotNetHighCharts?

Comment: If you use DotNetHighCharts dll, I have full example of timeSeriesZoomable, if you want I can write it here. May be it shows you a way.

Comment: Hi @AliRızaAdıyahşi that would be great, I'd appreciate that alot!

Answer (score 3):

Chart

```
public static Highcharts TimeSeriesZoomable(Series[] Series, Number MinRange, Number PointInterval, DateTime PointStartDate, AxisTypes XAxisType = AxisTypes.Datetime, string Title = "", string SubTitle = "", string XAxisTitle = "", string YAxisTitle = "", string ToolTipFormat = "", string YAxisLabel = "")
    {
        Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .SetOptions(new GlobalOptions { Global = new Global { UseUTC = false } })
            .InitChart(new Chart { ZoomType = ZoomTypes.X, SpacingRight = 20, DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Area, Height = 300, BorderRadius = 0 })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = Title })
            .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle { Text = SubTitle })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis
            {
                Type = XAxisType,
                MinRange = MinRange,
                Title = new XAxisTitle { Text = XAxisTitle }
            })
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis
            {
                Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = YAxisTitle },
                Min = 0.6,
                StartOnTick = false,
                EndOnTick = false,
                Labels = new YAxisLabels
                {
                    Formatter = @"function() { return this.value +' " + YAxisLabel + "';}"
                }
            })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Shared = true/*, Formatter = @"function() { return ''+ this.x +' - '+ this.y +' " + ToolTipFormat + "'; }" */})
            .SetLegend(new Legend { Enabled = true, VerticalAlign = VerticalAligns.Top })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Line = new PlotOptionsLine
                {
                    LineWidth = 3,
                    Marker = new PlotOptionsLineMarker
                    {
                        Enabled = false,
                        States = new PlotOptionsLineMarkerStates
                        {
                            Hover = new PlotOptionsLineMarkerStatesHover
                            {
                                Enabled = true,
                                Radius = 5
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    Shadow = false,
                    States = new PlotOptionsLineStates { Hover = new PlotOptionsLineStatesHover { LineWidth = 3 } },
                    PointInterval = PointInterval,
                    PointStart = new PointStart(PointStartDate)
                },
                Spline = new PlotOptionsSpline
                {
                    LineWidth = 3,
                    Marker = new PlotOptionsSplineMarker
                    {
                        Enabled = false,
                        States = new PlotOptionsSplineMarkerStates
                        {
                            Hover = new PlotOptionsSplineMarkerStatesHover
                            {
                                Enabled = true,
                                Radius = 5
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    Shadow = false,
                    States = new PlotOptionsSplineStates { Hover = new PlotOptionsSplineStatesHover { LineWidth = 3 } },
                    PointInterval = PointInterval,
                    PointStart = new PointStart(PointStartDate)
                },
                Area = new PlotOptionsArea
                {
                    //FillColor = new BackColorOrGradient(new Gradient
                    //{
                    //    LinearGradient = new[] { 0, 0, 0, 300 },
                    //    Stops = new object[,] { { 0, "rgb(116, 116, 116)" }, { 1, Color.Gold } }
                    //}),
                    LineWidth = 1,
                    Marker = new PlotOptionsAreaMarker
                    {
                        Enabled = false,
                        States = new PlotOptionsAreaMarkerStates
                        {
                            Hover = new PlotOptionsAreaMarkerStatesHover
                            {
                                Enabled = true,
                                Radius = 5
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    Shadow = false,
                    States = new PlotOptionsAreaStates { Hover = new PlotOptionsAreaStatesHover { LineWidth = 1 } },
                    PointInterval = PointInterval,
                    PointStart = new PointStart(PointStartDate)
                }
            })
            .SetSeries(Series);
        return chart;
    }
```

Chart Data

```
public static Series GetTimeSeriesData(IQueryable<YourModel> model, ChartTypes ChartType)
    {
        List<Series> Series = new List<Series>();

        var chartSeries = model.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                        .Select(g => new
                        {
                            Name = g.Key,
                            Data = g.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()
                        }).ToArray();

        foreach (var item in chartSeries)
        {
            object[] data = item.Data.Cast<object>().ToArray();
            Series localSeries = new Series { Name = item.Name, Data = new Data(data), Type = ChartType };
            Series.Add(localSeries);
        }

        return Series;
    }
```

Usage

```
IQueryable<YourModel> model;
ChartData chartData = new ChartData();
Highcharts chart = new HighChart("chart_time_series");

try
{
    model = db.ClassInstanceDetails.AsQueryable();
    chartData = GetTimeSeriesData(model, ChartTypes.Line);
    chart = TimeSeriesZoomable(chartData.ToArray(), another_options);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

And full examples of charts : http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/85324

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Highcharts.Net? If so, I'm not sure how much help I can be (I have only done it manually, creating my own objects and converting to JSON etc, which I found to give me complete control, albeit with more effort)
Anyway, this usually largely depends on how your X-axis needs to behave... it appears like it would just be discrete datetime values, (not automatically sequential), and so your object array probably needs to be composed of X- and Y-values, rather than just the Y-values, as it appears you have there.

This next part really depends on how your implementation works, so please excuse the pseudo-pseudo-code... 
You either need a 2D array:
eg: data = [[1,1], [2,5], [3,4]...]

or something more concrete: I use a class which has an X and a Y property (amongst other things), but you could try anonymous types perhaps?
eg [{x=1, y=1}, {x=2, y=5}, {x=3, y=4}...] etc

Does this help at all?
Note: you will probably want to read up a bit on how to convert your datetime values for your x-axis - I had to calculate ticks from Epoch etc

Comment: Hi @baldric, yes I am using highcharts.net. I'm still quite new to development so struggling a bit.